# Understanding density transformations

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

The following is the well known statement about transforming a probibility density $p_X(x)$ to $p_Y(y)$ under diffeomorphism $f(x)$:
$$p_Y(y)=p_X(f^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|.$$

The traditional proof that I remember myself is:
$$p_Y(y_0)=\frac{d {\rm Pr}(Y\leq y)}{dy}(y_0)=\frac{d {\rm Pr}(X\leq x)}{dx}(x_0)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|=p_X(x_0)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|$$

Where I used the chain rule in the middle step. However now thinking about it, I have problems understanding it, because it is not anymore obvious to me that:
$${\rm Pr}(X\leq x)={\rm Pr}(Y\leq f(x))$$

Don't we need a condition like $f$ being measure preserving for such an assumption to hold?

Answer (score 0):

$f$ will need to be one-to-one for simple tranformation formulas to work. Otherwise, you will need to break up the domain into piecewise one-to-one regions. For example, $Y=X^2$ is only one-to-one if X is strictly positive or negative.

Comment: Thank you very much. You said one can break the domain and get the relation, so I don't think thats a problem.

Beside isn't your answer a bit different from what I have asked?

Comment: @Cupitor I was commenting on your question about the step ${\rm Pr}(X\leq x)={\rm Pr}(Y\leq f(x))$. For that to work, $f(x)$ needs to be 1-to-1. The Jacobian ensures that if $P(X\leq x)$ is a probability measure, then $P(Y\leq f(x))$ is also a probability measure.

Comment: @Cupitor what did you correct...I wasn't pointing out an error. I was addressing your question on necessary elements of density transformations. You're understanding is generally correct, but you need to recognize that the Jabobian factor in the chain rule preserves the measure.

Comment: I see. So I corrected the necessary element :)
I know the role of the Jacobian, but I don't see a mathematical justification for it. Thats the point.

Comment: @Cupitor have you read about how it's derived? I'd think that preservation of measure is a pretty good justification. It's basically just adjusting the transformed density to account for distortions (as measured by the determinant at each point along the transformation).

Comment: I understand your argument. But I am looking for a rigorous proof. I actually wrote how it is derived, but that justification does not satisfy me anymore. With a non-measure theoretic probability definition ${\rm Pr}(X\leq x)={\rm Pr}(Y\leq y)$ is obvious but not with a measure theoretic one.